# Как в ubuntu посмотреть загруженность памяти дополнениями от Firefox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, firefox, linux-mint

Как в ubuntu посмотреть загруженность памяти дополнениями от Firefox ? 
Вот характеристики нетбука :

Acer Aspire One D270 / Intel Atom 1,6Ghz / **2Gb RAM** / Mint Linux 18.1 Serena Mate / **Firefox 54** (64bit)

Все браузеры очень прожорливы до оперативной памяти. Есть желание разобраться, возможно ли как-то отслеживать переполнение? Делать сжатие или иные функции? Применительно только для слабых машин.

В гугл хроме можно убивать отдельные процессы (есть монитор процессов браузера), вот хочется решить задачу с фаерфоксом.
Какие ориентиры для поиска?

Comment: Следует отредактировать текст и использовать знаки препинания.

Comment: Это вопрос про Firefox -- ищите его средства. Я бы ещё поставил Firebug, возможно там уже есть нечто подобное.

Answer (score 1):

В адресной строке наберите `about:memory` и нажмите Enter.